# Azure pipeline parameter as secret variable

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, gitlab-api

I want to pass PAT as pipeline parameter to script(gitlab.sh) that calls Gitlab REST API:

**gitlab.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

MY_PAT="${MY_PAT}" #I want this to be secret and not printed in logs

function rest_api {
 curl -sSL -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN:$MY_PAT" -X POST
   --data '{"name": "my-group","path": "my-group"}'
   https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/groups 
}

rest_api
```

**azure-pipelines.yml**

```
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    parameters:
     - name: myPAT
      displayName: 'My PAT'
      type: string  
    
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - script: |  
        echo "Creating group in Gitlab"
        export MY_PAT=${{parameters.myPAT}} #how can I pass this secretly to gitlab.sh
        bash -x gitlab.sh
      condition: and(succeeded(), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/feature'))
      displayName: 'Creating group in Gitlab'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set a secret you should use logging command as below

```yaml
- bash: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MY_PAT;issecret=true]${{parameters.myPAT}}"
  name: SetSecret
```

On the next task you should have `MY_PAT` secret variable available. However, since you will pass it as runtime parameter it could be printed in the logs.

And for instance

```yaml
parameters:
- name: myPAT
  displayName: 'My PAT'
  type: string

trigger: none
pr: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'


steps:
- bash: |
    echo "You can use macro replacement to get secrets, and they'll be masked in the log: ${{parameters.myPAT}}"

- bash: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MY_PAT;issecret=true]${{parameters.myPAT}}"
  name: SetSecret

- bash: |
    echo "You can use macro replacement to get secrets, and they'll be masked in the log: $(MY_PAT)"
```

For first print I got:

> You can use macro replacement to get secrets, and they'll be masked in the log: MySecret

and fot the second:

> You can use macro replacement to get secrets, and they'll be masked in the log: ***

So passing secret via parameters you may expose it. Be aware of that.

I created a feature request to support runtime paramaters as secret [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1280894/secret-type-for-runtime-paramaters.html). Feel free to vote up if you consider this as valuable feature.

```yaml
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
parameters:
 - name: myPAT
  displayName: 'My PAT'
  type: string  

steps:
- checkout: self
- bash: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MY_PAT;issecret=true]${{parameters.myPAT}}"
  name: SetSecret

- script: |  
    echo "Creating group in Gitlab"
    bash -x gitlab.sh
  condition: and(succeeded(), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/feature'))
  displayName: 'Creating group in Gitlab'
  env:
    MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: $(MY_PAT) # the recommended way to map to an env variable
```

and then you can use `MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR` in you sh file as [enviromnet variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#environment-variables)

Comment: thanks but will setSecret be accessible in script file gitlab.sh; I have already tried with setting var as secret but that(MY_PAT) wasn't accessible

Comment: You don't need to have setSecret accessible in sh file. In you case you need to add env mapping to have this value mapped as environment variable.

Comment: I have already tried setting in env var, that doesn't serve my purpose. May I please request you to revisit question? I want PAT to call REST API from script file

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. All above should do the job. It sets env variable which you can access from file. Previously you set variable via export. However, did you try approach which I show you? As far as I'm aware `export` is not recommended approach for doing this. I did as above in the past and it was fine.

Comment: I got it now..thanks..so export secret variable is not recommended; is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yeah. This is why there is mapping system created. @Wanderer Can you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful for you?